# python: error when running __new__? not invoking __init__

Tags: python, new-operator, init

I was reading Python documentation regarding inheritance and use of `__new__`  and `__init__`

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization

I am trying to create a class 'config' which will be a generic class with all basic methods common to all my projects

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class MyConfig(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Config new")
        return cls

    def __init__(self):
        print("Config init")
```

Then, when I create a new project I'll import that generic `config` class and create an specific configuration class for that project

```py
# from config import MyConfig

class MyConfiguration(MyConfig):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyConfiguration, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Configuration init")
```

When I instantiate my configuration I would spec to both `__new__` and `__init__` methods to run, but only runs `__new__`

```py
c = MyConfiguration()
```

This is the output:

```
Config new
```

Documentation says:

> If `__new__()` is invoked during object construction and it returns an instance or subclass of cls, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will be invoked like `__init__(self[, ...])`, where self is the new instance and the remaining arguments are the same as were passed to the object constructor.

> If `__new__()` does not return an instance of cls, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

As only output comes from `__new__` method, that means that I am doing something wrong because the `__init__` method is not being invoked.

any help would be welcome.

Comment: `__init__()` will only be invoked if your `__new__()` returns something that it can be validly invoked on - namely, an instance of the class.  You're returning the class itself.

Comment: thx. I guess that I did not fully understand what __new__ should return.

Comment: More precisely, `__init__` is only called if `__new__` returns an instance of (a subclass of) `cls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__init__()` will only be invoked if your `__new__()` returns something that it can be validly invoked on - namely, an instance of the class.

In your example, you're returning the class itself.

This is one way you can do it:
To create an instance of your class, and return it instead of returning the class itself:

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class MyConfig(metaclass=ABCMeta):
      def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            instance = super(MyConfig, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
            print("Config new")
            return instance
      
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("Config init")

class MyConfiguration(MyConfig):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MyConfiguration, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            print("Configuration init")
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
      c = MyConfiguration()
```

Output:

```
Config new
Config init
Configuration init
```